# iOS - Data persist once into Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save a bunch of data into core data. I could manage to save all the data into core data but it make no sense to have duplicate data inside core data because the function will be execute once on every build of the project. The approach that I am thinking now is empty the entity's record before I am adding new record to it. Just want to know is that got another way around to make sure that the data only persist once?

```
func persistCurrencyData() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let currencyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Currency", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    let countryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Country", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    for currency in currencies {
      let currencyObject = CurrencyCore(entity: currencyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

      currencyObject.setValue(currency.code, forKeyPath: "code")
      currencyObject.setValue(currency.name, forKeyPath: "name")

      for country in currency.country! {
        let countryObject = CountryCore(entity: countryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        countryObject.setValue(country.name, forKeyPath: "name")
        countryObject.setValue(country.code, forKeyPath: "code")
        countryObject.setValue(country.continent, forKeyPath: "continent")
        countryObject.setValue(country.continentCode, forKeyPath: "continentCode")

        countryObject.currency = currencyObject
      }
    }

    do {
      try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Thanks to @Wain for giving me the idea. Basically what I done to solve the saving of duplicate data in core data is I included an GUID in my JSON file. Every time the code read the JSON file, it will save GUID into `NSUserDefault` and save data into core data. When it wants to read JSON file again in the next build, it will check whether the GUID is same as previous saved GUID. If it is different, the code will read the JSON file and repeat the process above. If not, it will proceed and ignore it.

```
func requestCurrenciesData() {
    getCurrenciesDataFromFileWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in
      var json: [String: AnyObject]

      do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! [String: AnyObject]

        guard let currencyData = CurrencyData(json: json) else {
          print("Error initializing object")
          return
        }

        self.currencies = currencyData.currency!

        // Checking the JSON's id is same as previous read
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let id = defaults.stringForKey("id")
        {
          if id == currencyData.id {
            let notification = NSNotification(name: "CurrenciesDataUpdate", object: nil)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)

            return
          }
        }

        self.persistCurrencyDataForId(currencyData.id)

        let notification = NSNotification(name: "CurrenciesDataUpdate", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
      } catch {
        print(error)
        return
      }
   }
}

func persistCurrencyDataForId(id: String) {
    // Save the new JSON's id into NSUserDefaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(id, forKey: "id")

    // Delete all the records in existing table
    deleteRecordsFromEntity("Country")
    deleteRecordsFromEntity("Currency")

    // Insert the new records
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let currencyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Currency", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let countryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Country", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    for currency in currencies {
      let currencyObject = CurrencyCore(entity: currencyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

      currencyObject.setValue(currency.code, forKeyPath: "code")
      currencyObject.setValue(currency.name, forKeyPath: "name")

      for country in currency.country! {
        let countryObject = CountryCore(entity: countryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        countryObject.setValue(country.name, forKeyPath: "name")
        countryObject.setValue(country.code, forKeyPath: "code")
        countryObject.setValue(country.continent, forKeyPath: "continent")
        countryObject.setValue(country.continentCode, forKeyPath: "continentCode")

        countryObject.currency = currencyObject
      }
    }

    do {
      try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }

func deleteRecordsFromEntity(entityName: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let coordinator = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
      try coordinator.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: managedContext)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where is the data you're importing coming from? Does it change between each time this code runs? Does each object have a unique identifier?

Comment: @Wain The data is extracted from a [json](https://github.com/DavidODW/world-currencies) file and the data is the same for each time the code runs. I believe the data that extracted have unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can say 'if i have any currency entries in the data store, don't add more'. That could be done by adding a flag to use defaults or something like that when you do the first import, but a better option is to check the data store to see if it has any currency entries. To do this create a fetch request for `currencyEntity` and use `countForFetchRequest:error:` before you carry on with `for currency in currencies {`. If the count is greater than zero then you should return instead of processing the loop.

To be more efficient this check should actually be before you download and process the JSON...

Comment: The project will read the json that I included in the NSBundle. If I implement the solution that you proposed, is that have any significant effect on the app's performance?

Comment: a download would be the biggest cost, but you still don't need to read the file in and process it if you already have it in the data store

Comment: ok, I will try to check the currency entries before add any new entries. I will accept your answer.

Comment: If I include a "GUID" in json file and save the GUID in NSUserDefaults after the first read of the json file. Every build time the code will be checking the GUID is the same as previous read. If same, the code will skip to read the json and proceed. Let say I have some data changes in my json file in the future, I just need to change to different GUID and the code will be reading the new json file. Is this should work better?

Comment: Yes, that is a fine solution and good planning for the future